# Removing text from brackets if particular word exist

Tags: python, python-re

I have two strings for which trying to remove text inside bracket if certain word exist inside bracket, for s1 i am able get desired output by using below regex but for s2 same logic is not work. don't know whats gng wrong.

```
s1 = '((Xyz_lk eou ) some stuff (XYZ_l))) (vc vbn XyZ no.s)'
s2 = '( 100 % eou ) - 1h-imidazole 5,5- [ 1,1 -biphenyl ] -4,4 -diylbis [ 2 -- 2-pyrrolidinyl ] hydrochloride'
```

logic :

```
vc1 = re.sub(r"\s*\((\w|\s)*(eou|eou)(\w|\s)*\)", "", s1)
print(vc1)
vc2 = re.sub(r"\s*\((\w|\s)*(eou|eou)(\w|\s)*\)", "", s2)
print(vc2)
```

output

```
vc1: (some stuff (XYZ_l))) (vc vbn XyZ no.s)
vc2: ( 100 % eou ) - 1h-imidazole 5,5- [ 1,1 -biphenyl ] -4,4 -diylbis [ 2 -- 2-pyrrolidinyl ] hydrochloride
```

Comment: what is the certain word ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
vc1 = re.sub(r"\([^())]*eou[^)]*\)", "", s1)
print(vc1)
==> ( some stuff (XYZ_l))) (vc vbn XyZ no.s)


vc1 = re.sub(r"\([^())]*eou[^)]*\)", "", s2)
print(vc1)
==>  - 1h-imidazole 5,5- [ 1,1 -biphenyl ] -4,4 -diylbis [ 2 -- 2-pyrrolidinyl ] hydrochloride
```

Comment: As the the question, output of first should be

```(some stuff (XYZ_l))) (vc vbn XyZ no.s)```